# App.config - Values in <applicationSettings> fail, Values in <appSettings> work

Tags: c#, xml

In an effort to try to get ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[..] working again, I've created one **applicationSettings** element and one **appSettings** element in a single-project console application.

```
<applicationSettings>
 <el_testo.Properties.Settings>
   <setting name="ApplicationSetting" serializeAs="String">
     <value>Application Value</value>
   </setting>
 </el_testo.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
<appSettings>
 <add key="AppSetting" value="App Value"/>
</appSettings>
```

Here's my effort to retrieve the two values.

```
 Debug.WriteLine("---> ApplicationSettings Test");
 Debug.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationSetting"] + "");
 var applicationSettingsTest = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationSetting"];
 Debug.WriteLine(applicationSettingsTest);
 Debug.WriteLine("---> AppSettings Test");
 Debug.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppSetting"]);
 Debug.WriteLine("---> Complete");
```

And here are my results.

```
---> ApplicationSettings Test


---> AppSettings Test
App Value
---> Complete
```

I could just "settle" and use the **appSettings** construct. It would be kind of nice, however, to use the Settings tab on Project properties on this project and future projects. Here's what I've tried this far to make  work.

- There's only one project in this application. Therefore, I can't be setting the value in one project and trying to read it in another. (Additionally, **appSettings** works.)
- I verified that the project includes the assembly reference System.Configuration and the class includes the proper namespace reference (using System.Configuration;)
- I've double-checked spelling and case of the setting name in  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationSetting"].
- I've tried linking App.config to different XML Schema files, EnterpriseLibrary.Configuration.xsd and an XML Schema file I generated using the XML menu in Visual Studio.
- I've wiped the contents of the Debug and Release folders and rebuilt the project.

Comment: If you open machine.config you will see how appSettings is defined. But there is no section definition for applicationSettings so it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrectly trying to read your ApplicationSetting element as a key under appSettings with the following statement:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationSetting"]
```

This means your are trying to get the value of this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ApplicationSetting" value="xxxx" />
</appSetting>
```

Instead; when you add an application setting using the project properties, it creates a settings class extending the ApplicationSettingsBase class, create properties with the name of your settings and will also add necessary configSection and a default config element in your app.config file. Why not just create and use that class which will give you type strict access to your application settings?

Just go to Project/e_testo Properties/Settings and add ApplicationSetting with scope Application

You can then access the ApplicationSetting by

```
var applicationSettingsTest = Properties.Settings.Default.ApplicationSetting
```

Comment: You're welcome. Can you mark this as answer if it fixed your problem? Thanks